# Cannot select story in Tekken 7

Tags: tekken-7

On Playstation 4 after I installed Tekken 7, I cannot select the story. It is showing the "Please wait while installing the game data" message.

Answer (score 1):

If your PS4 is still downloading a game, you are able to run it after some really necessary data is downloaded. It allows you to use some in-game features, but until all data is downloaded, you do not have permission to access all content in the game.